# How to iterate over a multimap to satisfy an IF condition - C++

Tags: c++, maps

I have two multimaps, one with Dates and floats, the other with Times and floats. Both maps have duplicate values. In the multimap with dates as keys, i iterate over it and store the **maximum** float value for a date that was entered by the user. Then, in my next map I want to retrieve the times for the date where this value exists. (All my data comes from a vector holding all these values I need). My goal is to print out the times that have the maximum float value for a date, so it could be at one time or more.

Currently, my program prints out all the times that hold that float value, including the times that do not belong to the date the user entered. How do i fix my logic so that i only retrieve the times that have the user's entered date, as well as the maximum value?

Code:

```
float maxVal = 0;
    for(std::multimap<Date, float>::iterator it = mapOption5Solar.begin(); it!=mapOption5Solar.end(); it++)
    {
        if(checkDate == it->first)
        {
            if(maxVal < it->second)
            {
                maxVal = it->second;
            }

        }
    }




    for(std::multimap<Time, float>::iterator it = mapOption5Time.begin(); it != mapOption5Time.end(); it++)
    {
        if(maxVal == it->second)
        {
            timeVec.add(it->first);
        }
    }
```

Comment: How date and time classes are related in code?

Comment: Date and Time are custom classes I have created. The Date object in one map stores the dates from a file with a float value assigned to the date in the file. There are also time values in the file, and the map with the Time values as keys holds the same float values as well.

Comment: Each Date in the file has a Time as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Date` and `Time` are not connected, then in no way. You cannot match time to a specific date.

I would recommend creating a structure, like below and store your data in `multimap<DateTime, float>`

```
struct DateTime {
    Date date;
    Time time;
};
```

Afterwards you can write

```
float maxVal = 0;
for(const auto& [dateTime, value] : mapOption5)
{
    if(checkDate == dateTime)
    {
        if(maxVal < value)
        {
            maxVal = value;
        }
     }
}

for(const auto& [dateTime, value] : mapOption5)
{
    if((checkDate == dateTime) && (maxVal == value)
    {
        timeVec.add(value);
    }
}
```